# Pulling coordinates for MapView annotations from MySQL database, but annotations aren't showing?

Tags: objective-c, annotations, mkmapview, sigabrt

I'm trying to pull coordinates for my MapView from a MySQL database, but for some reason my coordinates just aren't showing up on the MapView?

See below my code.

**MapViewController.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>    

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController  <MKMapViewDelegate> 
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dispensaries;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *data;
@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"
#import "JSONKit.h"

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize mapView;
@synthesize dispensaries;
@synthesize data;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {        
    [super viewDidUnload];

    NSLog(@"Getting Device Locations");
    NSString *hostStr = @"http://stylerepublicmagazine.com/dispensaries.php";
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"server output: %@", serverOutput);
    NSMutableArray *array = [[[serverOutput objectFromJSONString] mutableCopy] autorelease];   
    dispensaries = [serverOutput objectFromJSONString];
    NSLog(@"%@", [serverOutput objectFromJSONString]);

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {
            assert([dictionary respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]);

            CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {[[dictionary objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[dictionary objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]};

            MapViewAnnotation *ann = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] init];
            ann.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];
            ann.coordinate = coord;
            [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    }        

    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation     {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
    point.title = @"You Are Here";
    point.subtitle = @"Your current location";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}
```

**MapViewAnnotation.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MapViewAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
}    
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@end
```

**MapViewAnnotation.m**

```
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"

@implementation MapViewAnnotation    
@synthesize title, coordinate, subtitle;

-(void)dealloc{
    [title release];
    [super dealloc];
}    

@end
```

Comment: edited to make the code way more compact and likely easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be an issue with you expecting the wrong JSON:
You wrap the `serverOutput` in an array:

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[serverOutput objectFromJSONString]];
```

---

You try to access a JKDictionary (Json Kit dictionary) WITCH is infact an array and therefore doesn't answer to objectForKey:

try to make sure:

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {
    assert([dictionary respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]);
```

--

## potential Solution

I believe your extra wrapping makes it bad. try:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[[serverOutput objectFromJSONString] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Comment: I've implemented your solution, and it stops my app from crashing :) It also shows my current location, but for some reason it's still not displaying the annotations from my database on the mapview. See my updated code above.

Comment: well stop the debugger at the addAnnotation call and verify the data is ok at that point. then, you haven't shown us your class `MapViewAnnotation` so it's a bit of guesswork :)

Comment: Just posted my MapViewAnnotation code above :) I feel like I'm missing something elementary? Lol. I implemented an NSLog to make sure that the data/JSON works, and it all looks fine.

Comment: unrelated but ....  (void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidUnload]; ... is very likely wrong :D

Comment: Super weird, but I restarted xCode, and your initial answer just started working. LOL! Crisis averted, annotations appear, everything is amazing :) THX!